# Can mobx observable data persist between multiple screens?

Tags: flutter, mobx

I have a mobx class that stores an observable named value and an action named increment, i also have 2 screens and i want the value of the observable to change on the second screen if i increment it on the first screen but the value always restart if i change a screen.

It used to work for me that way using mobx in react native , even if i change the screen the state updates in all of the screens but in flutter it doesn't work that way.

Mobx class

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
part 'appstores.g.dart';

class AppStore = _AppStore with _$AppStore;

abstract class _AppStore with Store {
  @observable
  int x = 0;

  @action
  void increment() {
    x++;
  }
}
```

Screen 1

```
// the x value updates here
 Observer(
                    builder: (_) => Text("${store.x}"),
                  ),
                  ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (){store.addToOrders();},
                          child: Text('Disabled Button',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Screen 2

```
// but not here
 Observer(
                                  builder: (_) => Text('orders ${store.x}',
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      )),
                                ),
```

I want the value of the observable x to change on all off the sreens with i increment it in one of the screens. How can i acheive that ?

Comment: I'm not into flutter but it seems that you are instantiating AppStore for every screen. Take a look on how to have your AppStore as singleton instance and that way your data will persist.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: @laszlo I used Inherited widget instead

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a different store in each screen.

I think the best way to use the same instance is by injecting as a singleton. I'm using [getIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) and to inject I'm using registerLazySingleton method

```
getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => MyStore());
```

To access that on each screen you can do something like:

```
final store = getIt<MyStore>();
```